# Is it possible for two branches to conflict on a file when one branch doesn't even change that file?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-extensions

Our department deploys our test server by taking master and merging in + locally committing each branch (one branch per task). The deploy script will stop if it runs into a merge conflict, or if after merging all the tasks in, the code fails to compile.

Today we got a conflict between my branch, which changed "InspectionTemplateAction.java", and another branch which, according to the diffs shown in GitExtensions, made no changes to that file. I have tried rebranching both branches off of HEAD of master (so there's no problems from starting at different points in shared history), reverting whitespace changes, and all to no avail.

The really baffling part is that, according to GitExtensions, the other branch has never modified the conflicting file.

Is this a bug? Is there something obvious I'm missing? Are there some other troubleshooting options I can try?

Comment: The only related issue I can think of is when one branch deletes the file, the other doesn't and the ordering gets messed up.

Comment: Good idea. But neither branch deletes the file. If the other branch deleted it, the deletion would show up in the diff.

Comment: To see where git thinks it was changed, I'd do `git log --graph --decorate --oneline branch1...branch2 -- path/to/file`.  Also, I'd try `git check-attr --all` on the path in each branch.

Comment: and just for a flyer, try adding `-X renormalize` to the merge options

Comment: what does "rebranching" mean (that is not a git function)? probably useful to show `git log path/to/file` for both branches, i.e. show something specific and ask "what's wrong here when I do this, and get this output?" rather than "wrong! something! <arm gestures> why?" =)

Comment: What does "according to the diffs shown in GitExtensions" mean? Are you looking at the diffs of each of the commits on the branch, or are you looking at the diff between the tip of the branch and the branch point? They may give different results if the branch modifies the file, and then reverts the modification.

Comment: [`git merge` shows exactly what causes it to report a conflict](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_how_conflicts_are_presented). Post the actual conflict, please.

Comment: "According to the diffs shown in GitExtensions, made no changes to that file". **What does plain Git say?** Please use `git diff`.

Comment: It seems we can't vote to close a question with an open bounty.  I don't see any way to solve this without providing the information multiple people have requested and addressing the issues multiple people have pointed out, so I'm downvoting this for nonresponsiveness, for being an idle complaint rather than a question.